# Getting color of pixel in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm able to store a specific color into one pixel in the Bitmap Display of the MARS Simulator (So I'm using MIPS).

Using this code:

```
.data
.text

main:
    #Storing color in $gp
    li $t1, 0x00ffffff
    sw $t1, 0($gp)

    #Getting color from $gp???????
    lw $t2, 0($gp)

    #Printing it out
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall
```

However, after that pixel is given a specific color, I later in my program want to check what the color of a specific pixel is.
I used sw, to put the color in the pixel,
and thought I could retrieve the color using lw; but it gives me

> 16777215

Instead of the color.

**How can I get the color from a specific pixel in the MIPS Bitmap Display?**

Comment: I don't see the problem. You've set the color to something specific, and you get the same thing back. What else would you expect?

Comment: `16777215` == `0xFFFFFF` It's the same value, just different formatting, base 10 "decimal" vs base 16 "hexadecimal". To get particular R/G/B part of it, you can use shift right instruction to shift by 0/8/16 bits, and then `and` to mask only lowest 8 bits, to get 0-255 value per colour channel. Or you can use `lbu $t2,0($gp)` `lbu $t3,1($gp)` `lbu $t4,2($gp)` to read it per bytes (much less efficient, but may be easier to understand how that `word` value is split into colour channels). I'm now not sure what is the format, ABGR? (i.e. red on +0, green on +1, blue on +2, padding junk +3 (alpha))

Comment: As always with these kind of questions, make sure you understand the values in computer are encoded in bits (i.e. native for CPU is "binary" encoding, just 0 and 1), and why/how the decimal/hexadecimal values written in source gets converted to bits, and vice versa. You should be able to calculate conversion from any base to any other base on paper (for values < 100k without calculator), at that point you understand numeral systems enough, and you should also see why 16777215 == 0xFFFFFF, and why hexadecimal formatting is friendly in case you want to see particular byte values inside word val.

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks a lot! That expained it very well and it's working now! If you like, you can copy/paste your comment in an answer so I can accept it. ;)